# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer

Tags: mysql, magento2

I am trying to create, modify and update products from the Magento 2.3.7 backend and it shows me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('maribuco_gzq7omh'@'localhost') does not exist, query was: UPDATE `mg21_catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `type_id` = ?, `sku` = ?, `has_options` = ?, `required_options` = ?, `created_at` = ?, `updated_at` = ? WHERE (entity_id = '495')
```

I have tried almost everything I found on the net and could not solve the problem. It would be helpful if someone can help me out.

My Magento 2 installation is on a shared server.

I hope your help, thank you!

Comment: Does the user `maribuco_gzq7omh` exist? If yes then, is the Magento and the database in the same machine/server? If not then this connection string is wrong `'maribuco_gzq7omh'@'localhost'`.

Comment: The user exists, and the Magento installation and database are on the same server

Comment: I assume that you have successful tried connecting to it using a tool (workbench or phpMyAdmin etc.) exactly as `maribuco_gzq7omh` on `localhost`, right? Is the database  using the default port (`3306`) or a defined with a different port?

Answer (score 1):

Temporary fix:

```
CREATE USER maribuco_gzq7omh;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'maribuco_gzq7omh'@;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```